# Find if ISOWeek() is shared between two months

Tags: go, time

Need a function that takes in a number ISOWeek() and returns if the ISOWeek is shared between two months or not?

For eg: Week Number 27 (Year 2020) is shared between months June and July whereas weeks like 23,24,25,26 are present only in one month.

Expected function sample code:

```
func IsShared(week, year int) bool {
    weekStartMonth = week.Start().Month() // sample for illustration
    weekEndMonth = week.End().Month() // sample for illustration
    if weekStartMonth == weekEndMonth {
        // Not Shared between months
        return false
    } else {
        // Shared between months
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the months of the first and last day of the week are the same. To get the first and last days of the week, check out [Date range by week number Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300644/date-range-by-week-number-golang/52303730#52303730)

Comment: Can you reopen this? I am looking for something more specific. The function above doesn't give enddate for a weekyear. If that is available, I'd be able to implement it

Comment: The marked duplicate contains a `WeekRange()` function which returns the first and last days of the given week. You just have to call `Month()` on both and compare.